# Create buffer and fill it with random numbers

Tags: c, random, buffer

I would like to create a buffer and then write random data in it.

here's what I got so far

```
uint8_t size = 10;
int* buffer = malloc (size*sizeof(uint8_t));
int i;
for (i=0; i<size; i++)
{
buffer[i]=(rand()%100)+1;
}
printf("Content of buffer = %d\n", buffer);
```

the result is wandom yes but only 8 numbers instead of 10.

I would like to get a buffer with the content of size and random numbers in it.

thanks in advance

Comment: write `printf("Content of buffer = %d\n", buffer[i]);` inside the `for` loop.

Comment: http://ideone.com/2wSIbY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
malloc (size*sizeof(int))
```

instead of

```
malloc (size*sizeof(uint8_t))
```

or maybe you need

```
uint8_t* buffer = malloc (size*sizeof(uint8_t));
```

It depends if you want a buffer of 10 `int` of a buffer of 10 `uint8_t`.

For printing the content of the buffer use:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
  printf("%d\n", buffer[i]) ;
}
```

Following line only prints the *address* of the buffer.

```
printf("Content of buffer = %d\n", buffer);
```

Comment: @raddirad: if this is the answer to your question, you should click on the green check mark at the top of the answer.

Comment: @ Michael Walz, Done :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a buffer of arbitrary size allocated with random data, you may want to seed your random number generator with the current time and then call `random()` repeatedly:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *allocate_random_heap_buffer(size_t size) {
    time_t current_time = time(NULL);
    srandom((unsigned int) current_time);
    char* allocatedMemory = (char *) malloc(size);

    for (int bufferIndex = 0; bufferIndex < size; bufferIndex++) {
        uint8_t randomNumber = (uint8_t) random();
        allocatedMemory[bufferIndex] = randomNumber;
    }

    return allocatedMemory;
}
```

Comment: It is not pure C. I't is some sort of mix C and C++ (

Comment: @DennisV.R.: Yeah, you can probably compile it for `C` if you use the `C` headers like `time.h` instead. Since this is a question tagged with `C` I updated my answer.

Comment: This code is still in C++. In pure C there is no concept of nullptr. Please use NULL. Don't use char as one byte. The right way — to use type uint8_t with appropriate header file and sizeof(uint8_t) for malloc